# 404 error admin-ajax.php page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to import products from Amazon to my Wordpress website, using a plugin which I developed myself. The plugin uses the Wordpress Ajax function to loop over all the products and creating a post for each product.

The plugin works almost fine, but it takes a while for importing all products and every time after importing exact 496 items, the Firebug console gives a 404 error for the admin-ajax.php file.

See: http://only-media.nl/404.PNG for a screenshot.

Strange, cause it does work during importing the first 496 items, but then it gives a 404 error. The plugin needs to import 800 products, so it's not done yet either. Anyone who knows a solution???? I'm hosting at hostgator, don't know it's usefull information but still..

EDIT: I think I fixed it. Seems like the script returned a 404 error, because the Ajax script takes too long to finish and response. Cause when I turned error reporting on, the script returned every loop an error of a variable which wasn't declared, and all products where added successfully. After I turned error reporting off, I got a 404 error again, after adding 400 products. So I guess I have to return a response every loop. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: maybe during the loop it gets an empty string (wrong product page ??)

Comment: Sorry for my delayed answer. But the problem is solved! Turns out that the system requires an answer from the ajax page within a limited of time. So I echo'd something on the end of the script, which worked.